# How to rotate a box in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve a clipper as shown in the below image. I am not getting what i have been expecting can anyone help me?
[image: Clipper]

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and what are you getting? I think using a container with rounded borders and a transform with a rotation would do the trick, but only if you don't mind the contents of the figure being rotated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this Clipper as shown in your image, you can do it like this :

```
Transform.rotate(
      angle: -5,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ),
    ),
```